# Generate getTick() in keil using stm32cube(HAL libary) for stm32l053r8 nucleo

Tags: stm32

how to generate the getTick() function in keil using stm32cube(HAL library) for stm32l053r8 nucleo board........

```
void Pedometer::newStep()
 {
    old_time = new_time; //time in msec of last step
    new_time = getTick(); //time in msec of new step
    float time = new_time - old_time; //time in msec between 
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the HAL_GetTick funtion in CubeL0.

Syntax:

```
uint32_t HAL_GetTick ( void )
```

(Refer page no. 56 of the document "Description of STM32L0xx HAL drivers")